# mysql: How to get a reusable connection_id?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using `mysql_connect()` to get `$thread_id` for using with next query. but I read from php.net that `mysql_connect()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. I tested and found found out the `$thread_id` is not working with the `mysqli_connect()`.

> mysql_connect: Opens or reuses a connection to a MySQL server.
>
> mysqli_connect: Opens a connection to the MySQL Server running on.

currently, my working code is:

```
$link = mysql_connect($this->_wpdb->dbhost, $this->_wpdb->dbuser, $this->_wpdb->dbpassword);
$thread_id = mysql_thread_id($link);
```

when mysql_connect() get removed in the future, how can I change my code to work with mysqli ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting mysql to mysqli - how to get superglobal connection object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487375/converting-mysql-to-mysqli-how-to-get-superglobal-connection-object)

Comment: *"`$thread_id` is not working with the `mysqli_connect()`"* - I think you meant `mysql_thread_id()` is not working with the `mysqli_connect()` - That's because those are two different types of SQL functions. `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` do not mix. `$thread_id` is just a variable; it doesn't know you from Adam ;-)

Comment: yes, and that function is going to be replaced by mysqli_thread_id(). @ShankarDamodaran , that question is not connection_id specific.

Answer (score -1):

How is this not working? [mysqli.thread-id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.thread-id.php) From manual about returning values:

**mysql_thread_id()**

> The thread ID on success or FALSE on failure.

**mysqli_thread_id()**

> Returns the Thread ID for the current connection.

Comment: mysqli_thread_id() returns the thread id for the current connection. But I will use this thread id as a condition for next query.

Comment: Both functions return the same: current thread_id. I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: mysqli_thread_id() doesn't return the thread_id that previously used.

Comment: Same with mysql_thread_id(). You are assigning the `$link` to get the thread_id. `mysql_thread_id($link);` => `mysqli_thread_id($link);`

Comment: this works only when you currently is queering something. but between 2 queries, it doesn't return a value.

Comment: You didn't specified that you want it between 2 queries. Then create 2 variables, `$thread_id1` on first query and `$thread_id2` on second and use whatever you want.